# Can not access localhost/xampp on browser after running xampp successfully

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, centos, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on Linux (CentOS 6.5) server on Oracle Virtual Machine
following this guide https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html

I've done following procedure on terminal.

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.5.19-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

Initially xampp was working fine now 
I cannot access my localhost, the Browser is still showing  goes to offline mode and shows

> "Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse
>   the Web."

I have restarted xampp and system.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you give the output of the command thx:
netstat -ntplu

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# netstat -ntplu -
usage: netstat [-veenNcCF] [<Af>] -r         netstat {-V|--version|-h|--help}
       netstat [-vnNcaeol] [<Socket> ...]
       netstat { [-veenNac] -I[<Iface>] | [-veenNac] -i | [-cnNe] -M | -s } [delay]

Comment: <Iface>: Name of interface to monitor/list.
  <Socket>={-t|--tcp} {-u|--udp} {-S|--sctp} {-w|--raw} {-x|--unix} --ax25 --ipx --netrom
  <AF>=Use '-A <af>' or '--<af>'; default: inet
  List of possible address families (which support routing):
    inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6) ax25 (AMPR AX.25) 
    netrom (AMPR NET/ROM) ipx (Novell IPX) ddp (Appletalk DDP) 
    x25 (CCITT X.25)

Comment: you may be typing it with invalid arguments thats why the command netstat -ntplu is returning you its usage manual.
What i want to know is that if the services are already running because when you performed sudo opt/lampp/lampp start it said that it is already running

Comment: >[root@localhost lampp]# netstat -l
>Active Internet connections (only servers)
>Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address             State      
>tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                    *:*    LISTEN      
>tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*    LISTEN      
>tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp               *:*    LISTEN      
>tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*  LISTEN      
>tcp        0      0 *:46493                     *:*  LISTEN